# Unity API not pure php have problem to Post , How to solve it?

Tags: php, laravel, unity-game-engine, unity-webgl

i am trying to Post request Using Unity web request
i created a pure php API For Testing 
After that Web developer Created API For Me To Work on it 
but the Link is little different syntax of the pure php i was work on 
my Pure PHP Link is : 
  http://localhost/sqlconnect/register.php
The New API Link is :
http://localhost/fighting/public/player/register

so the first one is .php  is working 
the second one doesn't have .php extension and it is not working 
so , What is the Problem and How To Solve it 
BTW the both of them Tested and successful work on the Web browser

This one works Ver Well

```
  IEnumerator Register_New ()
{
  WWWForm form = new WWWForm();
    //   string form= "?player_name="+name_Field.text+"&password="+Password_Field.text+"&api_key=omar";
    form.AddField("player_name", name_Field.text);
    form.AddField("password", Password_Field.text);
    form.AddField("api_key", "omar");
    UnityWebRequest www = UnityWebRequest.Post ("http://localhost/sqlconnect/register.php", form);
    www.SendWebRequest();
    print(www.url);
    yield return www;}
```

This one Doesn't Work

```
 IEnumerator Register_New ()
{
  WWWForm form = new WWWForm();
    //   string form= "?player_name="+name_Field.text+"&password="+Password_Field.text+"&api_key=omar";
    form.AddField("player_name", name_Field.text);
    form.AddField("password", Password_Field.text);
    form.AddField("api_key", "omar");
    UnityWebRequest www = UnityWebRequest.Post ("http://localhost/fighting/public/player/register", form);
    www.SendWebRequest();
    print(www.url);
    yield return www;}
```

Comment: "This one Doesn't Work" doesn't help other to find out what is wrong. Post specific problem

Comment: @WebArtisan I Edited the Question

Comment: Have you setup rewrite rules for your localhost?

Comment: @RMcLeod No and i don't know what is it ! ? i don't very good experience working with API's sorry , Can you explain ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You say they work in the web browser. This leads me to believe that the endpoints are accepting GET requests rather than POST, since GET is what you do when you type in a URL into the address bar. And by the way, your commented code also looks like a GET with a querystring. Are you sure you should be posting to the endpoints? Try it with UnityWebRequest.Get just to be sure.